# TypeScript "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" in case of function parameters and generics

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

I can't wrap my head around this error.

What I'm trying to do: make a React Hook (shown as just a function here for simplicity) that takes another function as argument. That argument-function can only accept as own argument an object that has some specific properties (ex. page and pageSize for paginated API calls - could be more (a subtype), can't be less).

Here is some explicative code:

```js
interface MyParams {
    page: number;
    pageSize: number;
}
interface MyResponse {
    count: number;
    results: any[];
}

type Options<T extends MyParams, K extends MyResponse> = {
    getDataFn: (params: T) => Promise<K>;
    setData: (data: K) => void;
};

const elaborate = <T extends MyParams, K extends MyResponse>(
    options: Options<T, K>
) => {
    return options
        .getDataFn({ page: 0, pageSize: 100 }) // Error. Why?!
        .then((res) => options.setData(res));
};

elaborate<{}, MyResponse>({ // Error. Expected!
    getDataFn: (params) => Promise.resolve({ count: "0", results: [] }), // No error. Why?!
    setData: () => {},
});
```

TS PlayGround link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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

I get an error on line 19 (`.getDataFn({ page: 1, pageSize: 10 })`), that says: "Argument of type '{ page: number; pageSize: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
'{ page: number; pageSize: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MyParams'."

So it seems that the generic T could somehow NOT CONTAIN the `page` and `pageSize` properties.

Well, that is not true, because I also get an error on line 23, where I purposely tried to make such a type mistake. The error says: "Type '{}' does not satisfy the constraint 'MyParams'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MyParams': page, pageSize".

So I can't actually call the function `elaborate` and pass a generic T that does not satisfy the constraint, otherwise I get an error (as expected).

So, what is causing the error on line 19?

Also, I would expect an error on line 24 (`Promise.resolve({ count: "1", results: [] })`), where I purposely set count as "1" (string) instead of number, which doesn't satisfy the constraint `setData: (data: K) => void;` where `K extends MyResponse`.

Thanks to all who can shed some light on this...

**EDIT - MORE CONTEXT:**

I want that `T may contain some other properties`.

Ideally that main-function should take a `dataGetter` and handle its pagination automatically (code excluded). Other properties may be some filters, for example a `query: string` (that I handle).

It should be reusable for all paginated API, so it may have more or different subtypes, but `page` and `pageSize` are common to all.

Better code example:

```js
interface MyParams {
    page: number;
    pageSize: number;
}

interface MyResponse {
    count: number;
    results: any[];
}

type Options<T extends MyParams, K extends MyResponse> = {
    getDataFn: (params: T) => Promise<K>;
    setData: (data: K) => void;
};

const elaborate = <T extends MyParams, K extends MyResponse>(
    options: Options<T, K>,
    otherParams: Omit<T, 'page' | 'pageSize'>
) => {
    return options
        .getDataFn({ page: 0, pageSize: 100, ...otherParams })
        .then((res) => options.setData(res));
};

///////////////////////////

type MyAPIParams = {
    page: number;
    pageSize: number;
    query: string;
}

type MyAPIResponse = {
    count: number;
    results: {name: string, age: number}[];
    otherProperty: boolean;
}

const API = {
    GET_DATA: (params: MyAPIParams): Promise<MyAPIResponse> => Promise.resolve({ count: 0, results: [], otherProperty: true})
}

elaborate<MyAPIParams, MyAPIResponse>({
    getDataFn: API.GET_DATA,
    setData: (data) => { console.log(data.results, data.otherProperty) },
}, {query: 'test'});
```

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-W4QBxACiYQA+rUvWEve1OujC36A71GEMRmMICEMEWS78yutkDfRjoOfrZxsIPzkErYxkFlRtbG6Nx0lHZVx2gKdkEzFN1VIaRSAgU5zkue9HwvZ40nPYs1B+HQSn5aoIDmXlWhXP0OW3PcDyPGEZgo81FnmQ0BSXWcIA5awNBoNolkab8rHA9JhLgDloJvCcvH6SQYUUkhk1TRgcUgDMcXVTggA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because you say that `T extends MyParams`, which doesn't mean that `T` will be strictly equal to `MyParams`. `T` may contain some other properties; thus, when you try to pass `MyParams` to the `getDataFn` you get the error.

To solve it, you either can use the assertion:

```
getDataFn({ page: 0, pageSize: 100 } as T)
```

Another solution would be to have a generic parameter for the whole options. It works because `T` is definitely `Options<MyParams, MyResponse>` and `MyParams` and `MyResponse` can't be extended, however `T` may contain some extra properties, which doesn't bother us:

```
<T extends Options<MyParams, MyResponse>>
```

The last thing that you could do is remove generic and just expect `Options<MyParams, MyResponse>`:

```
const elaborate = (options:Options<MyParams, MyResponse>) => {}
```

The reason why you don't get the error with `Promise.resolve({ count: "1", results: [] })`, is simply that you purposely passed `{}` as first parameter, which doesn't allow the compiler to infer the types correctly. If you pass a expected type instead of `{}` you will see the error.

[playground for generic for the whole Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKcpwLYDOyA3gFDLIAOcA5hAFzIgCueARtANzlW0QDKwAF4MmrDlG4BfUqEixEKDACUIBSgHsQBFGQoINzcIxbsuPKGuYAbMAUZwQ6ANoBdaaVJh0lFAHlKMGAtAgAeABVkCAAPSBAAEyIMbFxCABpkAGko2IgEpPRVdRCIAD5kAF4SHjowABE4MDgAMRBGAApqVPtkcIBKSvLMKA08YB1QzNLuCh16xrgO+IXGTIGK8oA3DWB46W5SA20wKOs4Ng1cSErkCJy4xOQAoJDQ5Jx8AgyVNU1tMtK7Q0gWC2kY-UG1QoljAzCgIGQwJe2h4FAAdLUGk1Wu1iLw6IwAAwZah0QQiRgARkJhOQUj6qOQaLAAAs8u12pYCOtykjQQQ0XMsXBOWo+n19p4IGcLlcILiahB5ti2shOh9CDzkMNRuMIGiuRprJt5XiDEYwIwAOSEq0ZLk2OyMNx0vppHhClZqrXEKTu+ncIA)

**UPDATE**

Since you expect additional properties, we must adjust the types further. In the updated code, even though it seems correct, you get the same error,  `T extends MyParams` may have `page` or other property not as any number, but a specific one like page: `1`; thus, when you try to pass `page: 0`, typescript will complain about this.

The easiest way to fix it would be to remove `MyParams` from `T` and assign it back.

```
type RemoveMyParams<T extends MyParams> = Omit<T, keyof MyParams> & MyParams;
```

It works because `T` extends `MyParams`, not equal to `MyParams` and may have more narrowed values for the properties; therefore, we remove the keys of `MyParams` from `T` and add general `MyParams` to it, which will have properties as any number.

The difference between `extends` and `&` here is that `extends` is not strictly equal to `MyParams`, and adding `MyParams` with `&` is not generic, that's why `T` will have general `MyParams`, not a specific one.

```
type Options<T extends MyParams, K extends MyResponse> = {
  getDataFn: (params: RemoveMyParams<T>) => Promise<K>;
  setData: (data: K) => void;
};
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXrO8m)

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment! `T may contain some other properties` is exactly what I need... I edited the main post with more context.

Comment: Will then something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpxjMm) work for you?

Comment: The issue is that `T extends MyParams`  may have `page` not as a any `number`, but a specific one like `page: 1`, that's why you still get the error

Comment: You second example can't work either, because the API and APITypes are generated from an external codebase and I can't edit them.

Comment: What is `APITypes` ? Is it `MyAPIParams`?

Comment: Oooh I see now! Is there any way that I could "enforce" that `page: number` can't be restricted more (to for example `page: 1`), but HAS to accept `any number`?

Comment: Yes with APITypes I meant everything related to the API, so: `MyAPIParams` `MyAPIResponse` and the API itself

Comment: The easiest thing to do will be to remove `MyParams` from `APITypes `

Comment: `! Is there any way that I could "enforce" that page: number can't be restricted more`, there is a way to do that; however, it is still about removing `MyParams`, I don't think there is a better way of doing this. Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXrO8m)

Comment: will this work for you so I can update the answer?

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work perfectly, w/o having to modify anything related to the API! As my understanding the "key" of your solution is this: `type RemoveMyParams<T extends MyParams> = Omit<T, keyof MyParams> & MyParams;`. How does it work exactly? How can omitting and adding the same property-types make a different type? Could you please elaborate more in your answer to understand better?

Comment: Could you maybe also add some more words about the difference of the keywords `extends` and `&`? Seems that one allows for type-narrowing and the other doesn't. I Also reworked it to make it a little more reusable like this: `type MustHave<T, K> = Omit<T, keyof K> & K;` and `getDataFn: (params: MustHave<T, MyParams>) => Promise<K>;` [link](https://tsplay.dev/mAxJRN)

Comment: Updated the answer and reposting here. The difference between `extends` and `&` here is that `extends` is not strictly equal to `MyParams`, and adding `MyParams` with `&` is not generic, that's why `T` will have general `MyParams`, not a specific one.